# How to check the rate of increase of a variable in Java?

Tags: java, processing, physics

I am trying to obtain the rate of change (increase or decrease) of a variable in Java.

For example, I have a Processing program that changes the velocity of an object depending on the gravity and the amount of time the mouse button is held down.

I want to obtain the rate of change of the velocity variable for the last 5 seconds. 
Then check if it is decreasing is too slowly.

If it is too low, the gravity should increase to make it fall down faster.
otherwise, the gravity should also increase to decrease the velocity.

How could I check the location of the object?

Comment: nice homework !

Comment: In case you're wondering, this is known as differentiation (a topic in calculus).

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

There isn't a magical out-of-the-box solution for this.

How would you do this without a computer, with just a piece of paper and a pencil? Write down instructions, in English, that you can follow to figure out the rate of change of a variable.

One solution might be to add the last X values to an array or ArrayList, and then use that to calculate how much it's changing. Or maybe just store the value it was X frames ago, and then compare that to the current value.

The point is that there isn't just one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

java.awt.event.MouseEvent is triggered on both mouse pressed and mouse released. As MouseEvent extends InputEvent the method getWhen() gives you the system time in millisecods, further more MouseEvent has methods to get the location of the mouse. So, register a mouse listener that remembers the mouse-pressed and mouse-released time, that gives you how long the mouse has been pressed. Is the mouse listener starts and stop a counter, that count speed depends on your gravity variable, you'll easyly get how many count have taken place during the elapsed time.

Comment: Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. The question is not pure Java or Swing. Processing has its own input functionalities, and AWT or Swing stuff should not be used.

Comment: @KevinWorkman you're right, but the java tag, the reference to mouse button and the refernce to pointer location, reminds me a windowing toolkit. The only one I know in java is AWT and therefore Swing. Any other implementation looks like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Please try to understand what Processing is. Processing uses Swing and AWT behind the scenes. But you should not use Swing and AWT on top of Processing.